# how do i give a the first letter of an array called word a value?

Tags: java

I need to give a the first letter of a word a value.  How do i do this in arrays?  Its at the line

```
firstLetter=word.charAt(len);
```

---

```
    public class FirstNLast{

        private String word[];
        private String sentence = "";
        private String newWord;
        private StringBuilder strBuff;
        private int len;
        private char firstLetter;
        private char lastLetter;

    public FirstNLast(){

        word = sentence.split(" ");
        newWord = "";
        strBuff = new StringBuilder();
        len = 0;
        firstLetter = ' ';
        lastLetter = ' ';
         }

    public void setWord(String[] word){

        this.word = word;
         }

    public void compute(){

        len = word.length;
        firstLetter=word.charAt(len);
        lastLetter=word.charAt(len-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: `word.charAt(len)` how is it working? Since `word` is an array.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays don't have a first letter; they have a first element. In this case, that element is a String, and it has a first letter. So, you want the first letter of the first element:

```
firstLetter=word[0].charAt(0);
```